VROPS Report - VM usage summery
I have some application vms. Each application having separate folders. i need to get a summery report for that application vms. we are having VROPS to monitor and we can get cluster level and individual VM levels. some one can help how to get report based on the folders level DISK,memory, CPU usage summery report.

Do you have an option to use Resource Pools?

yes i have an options
